# Prove that the height of this triangle equals the sum of the radii of the cirles

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles, tangent-line

Take any equilateral triangle $ABD$, then extend the side $AB$ into a line. Take a point $C\in \overleftrightarrow{AB}$, and trace the line $\overleftrightarrow{CD}$. Circles $G$ and $E$ are both tangent to the equilateral triangle, and to the lines $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{AD}$. Prove that the height of the triangle $ABD$ equals the sume of the radii of the circles $G$ and $E$, regardless the position of point $C$ in the line $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$. Here's an image with some other elements: 
[image]

Note: Dotted lines in the image represent angle bisectors of the angles they cut through. It's easy to show that the centers of the circles must lie on those angle bisectors. $M$ is the mid-point of side $AB$. Some tangency points, such as $I$ and $J$ have also been marked.

Comment: Where is this from?

Comment: It's a modification of a problem on the Mathematics Teacher Journal. I can't remember the exact issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

$$\left.\begin{align}
p+r &= 2t \\
q+s &= 2t \\
p+q &= 2t + r + s
\end{align} \quad \right\rbrace \implies \quad t = r + s$$

Answer (score 2):

[image]

\begin{align}
r&=|GI|
,\quad
r_a=|EF|
,\quad h=|DM|=r_a+|EL|
,\\ 
\angle ADC&=
\tfrac\pi3-2\phi
=2\psi
,\\
\angle EDB&=\tfrac\pi6+\phi
,\\
\angle LDE&=\tfrac\pi6-\phi
=\tfrac12\angle ADC
=\psi
,\\
\angle EKD&=\angle GAD=\tfrac\pi3
,\\
|DK|&=|DA|
,\\
\triangle ADG &\cong
\triangle KDE
,\\
|EL|&=|GI|=r
.
\end{align}